# How to get in a string one word and the following words separated by space?

Tags: c#, string

In C# i have one string like this:

```
"nome varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO INCREMENT"
```

I have to search first of all if the string contains DEFAULT like this :
`string.Contains("DEFAULT")` and I'd concat the following string separated by space
SO i need to get this :

```
"DEFAULT NULL"
```

How can i do this with C# with framework 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to do:

```
string text = "nome varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO INCREMENT";
Match m = Regex.Match(text, @"DEFAULT\s+\S+");
if (m.Success)
{
    string output = m.Value;
}
```

Comment: Note: for the final word, it might need to be `DEFAULT(\s+\w+)?`

Comment: @MarcGravell You cannot create SQL having DEFAULT without following parameter.

Comment: @Ulubek nobody said it had to be strict SQL ;p Indeed, there are plenty of things I could do with default in SQL that would **not** match this - for example `default('abc')`. And that is *after* we have solved the mystery of a `NOT NULL` column that has a `NULL` default value ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, there are many ways to break this one ;) Nice catch about `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is probably better, but just for completeness, here's a way via Linq and `string.Split()`:

```
string test = "nome varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO INCREMENT";
string target = "DEFAULT";
string result = test.Split(' ').SkipWhile(item => item != target).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Match = " + target + " " + result);
else
    Console.WriteLine("No match found");
```